# Reversing coordinates of MultiPoint using Shapely?

Tags: python, coordinates, shapely

How to reverse the cooridnates order of this MultiPoint:

```
MULTIPOINT (92 169, 100 163.552380952381, 105.2167832167832 160, 266.7552447552447 50, 290 34.17142857142857, 302 26)
```

to this:

```
 MULTIPOINT (302 26, 290 34.17142857142857, 266.7552447552447 50,  105.2167832167832 160, 100 163.552380952381, 92 169)
```

I tried this and getting an error:

```
intPoints.coords[::-1])
```

> > > NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the order matters to you but the [shapely manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#collections-of-points) shows wrapping the `MultiPoint` in a `list`:

```
pprint.pprint(list(points.geoms))
```

so I would expect something like:

```
points = MultiPoint(list(points.geoms)[::-1])
```

to work. Though the manual makes no claims that `MultiPoints` honour the order of the input list.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is a MULTIPOINT.

Members of a multi-point collection are accessed via the geoms property or via the iterator protocol using in or list().

Here's an example:

```
>> from shapely import wkt
>> from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

>> p = wkt.loads("MULTIPOINT (92 169, 100 163.552380952381, 105.2167832167832 160, 266.7552447552447 50, 290 34.17142857142857, 302 26)")

>> list(p)
   [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>,
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>,
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>,
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>,
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>,
    <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x2...>]
>> inverted_mp = MultiPoint(list[::-1])
>> inverted_mp.wtk
   'MULTIPOINT (302 26, 290 34.17142857142857, 266.7552447552447 50, 105.2167832167832 160, 100 163.552380952381, 92 169)'
```